# How to Retrieve Video URL from YouTube on Video click in Android ?r

Tags: url, video, webview, youtube, chrome-custom-tabs

Step 1 : Open Youtube on Button Click (Webview or Chrome Custom Tab)
Step 2 : Click any Video From Youtube
Step 3 : On Video Click to Close Current Page It Means Close (Webview or Chrome Custom Tab)
Step 4 : On Close (Webview or Chrome Custom Tab) Set Video URL on Android TextView

Does any one have answer please help me out on this.

I tried to load youtube on webview and chrome custom tab but i'm not getting URL of video.

Comment: Please provide your code snippets. I can't help if you didn't insert the codes.

Answer (score 0):

We are getting URL on doUpdateVisitedHistory method of webview.
Code :

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public void doUpdateVisitedHistory(WebView view, String url, boolean isReload) {
                    super.doUpdateVisitedHistory(view, url, isReload);
                    Log.i(TAG, "doUpdateVisitedHistory:url " + url);
                }
            });
```